# How do I add a system preferences shortcut to desktop?

Tags: 11.04, system, docky

I removed all gnome panels and have created a beautiful desktop using "Docky" and "Slingshot" only. It sounds stupid but I'm a neat freak and panels in classic and Unity just didn't do it for me. I do not have access to my system settings, however. Is there a way I can add a real quick shortcut to the desktop so I can open it and pin to Docky?

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted if this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a .desktop file or simple bash script that runs `gnome-control-center`. Either that or you can drag and drop that launcher from Slingshot.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Elementary, then the simplest way I can tell you would be to open the terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, then type `gnome-control-center`. After it's launched, right click the icon for it in Docky and choose "Pin to Dock".